# How to print with Background Page Color Word 2013

Tags: microsoft-word

How do I print with the background color with Word 2013 - Windows 10? I set the background color by going to Page Background and then Page Color. When I go to print, the background color vanishes.

How do I do this with Word 2013 and Windows 10?(There is an option to print background colors and images. By default, this option is set to false.
From Word 2007, you can find this settings under "Word options" window, "Display" tab, "Printing options" section and the option is called "Print background colors and images".)

Answer (score 0):

#### How do I do this with Word 2013?

Please see the following instructions:

> 1. Open Word 2013 and click the "File" menu.
>
>    [image]
> 2. From the backstage view click the "Options" button.
>
>    [image]
> 3. In "Options", select the "Display" tab and then check the box titled "Print
>      Background Colors and Images". Click "OK" to save changes and exit.
>
>    [image]
>
> Now when you print, background colors or background images will now
>   show up. As mentioned above, this can use up a lot of ink. You may
>   want to keep this feature disabled until you are ready to print your
>   final copies.
>
> [image]

Source [Make Word 2013 Print Background Colors and Images](http://www.groovypost.com/howto/enable-office-2013-background-printing/)